# Sending logs to another service in Spring

Tags: java, spring, logging

I want to send all logs to another service via Http. I don't want to write custom webclient for this. Is there any log library which posts logs to web service? On the .net side, I can do it by using Serilog sink seq.  Is there any library like Serilog in Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4J has multiple appenders, one of which is HTTP Appender.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#HttpAppender

See requirements and example below:

> HttpAppender
>
> The HttpAppender sends log events over HTTP. A Layout must be provided
> to format the LogEvent.
>
> Will set the Content-Type header according to the layout. Additional
> headers can be specified with embedded Property elements.
>
> Will wait for response from server, and throw error if no 2xx response
> is received.

[image]

> Here is a sample HttpAppender configuration snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <Appenders>
    <Http name="Http" url="https://localhost:9200/test/log4j/">
      <Property name="X-Java-Runtime" value="$${java:runtime}" />
      <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
      <SSL>
        <KeyStore   location="log4j2-keystore.jks" passwordEnvironmentVariable="KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"/>
        <TrustStore location="truststore.jks"      passwordFile="${sys:user.home}/truststore.pwd"/>
      </SSL>
    </Http>
  </Appenders>

</xml>
```